# How to get list of all selected items of bundle product on detail page magento 2

Tags: magento2, bundle-product

How to get list of all selected items of bundle product on detail page magento2

Comment: you want all items for that bundle product in any page, right?

Comment: yes   all selected items for that bundle product

Comment: please check answer I uodated. and you add more details what you need in array ok.

Comment: it give me Mage error in magento 2

Answer (score 1):

Pleas try below code.

```
$product_id = 'your bundle product id';

$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $store_id = 1;
        $options = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Bundle\Model\Option')
            ->getResourceCollection()
            ->setProductIdFilter($product_id)
            ->setPositionOrder();
        $options->joinValues($store_id);
        $typeInstance = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type');
        $selections = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection($typeInstance->getOptionsIds($product), $product);
        foreach($selections as $selection){
            if($product->getSku() == $selection->getSku()){
                return $selection->getSelectionQty();
            }
        }
        print_r($selections);
```

Comment: how can i write in magneto 2

Comment: above code is for magento 1

Comment: it give me Mage error in magento 2

Comment: okay wait I will update you.

Comment: please try new one

Comment: $_storeManager  this give me error  i have added answer above its that works for me

Comment: you need to add bro that, but now check and update me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104634/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-junaid-ashfaq).

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<?php

$productId = 17; //any bundle product id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
        //get all the selection products used in bundle product.
        $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->getSelectionsCollection(
            $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product),
            $product
        );

    foreach ($selectionCollection as $proselection) {
                $selectionArray = [];
              echo  '<li>'; 
               echo $selectionArray['selection_product_name'] = $proselection->getName();
               echo '<br>';

               echo $selectionArray['selection_product_price'] = $proselection->getSelectionQty();
                 echo '</li>';
            }    




?>
</ul>
```

**this work for me**